# Remove item level data from GA4 transactions

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I have a bunch of transactions that included a "virtual product" that was not actually an item we sold, but rather part of a promotion where it would be included automatically based on the user's cart value. Unfortunately this throws off our metrics for "items purchased" during the time period of the promotion.

I'm wondering if it's possible to remove data at the product/item level from historical GA4 transactions.

Alternatively, I'd be open to implementing a filter to ignore that product if that were possible to do.

I've done a bit of research already and it looks like there are ways to remove or offset entire transactions, but this is not what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.